# Как организовывать модели с промежуточными таблицами

Tags: php, laravel, viewmodel

Представим, что есть таблица с проектами и таблица с сотрудниками. В одном проекте может быть задействовано несколько сотрудников и, соответственно, сотрудники могут участвовать в нескольких проектах, да еще и под разными должностями. Для реализации данной модели я использую три таблицы:

persons

- id
- full_name
- phone
- email

projects

- id
- name
- comment
- data
- status

project_has_person

- project_id
- person_id
- person_position

Как правильно реализовать модели?

Я реализовал модель projects

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projects extends Model
{
    //
    public function has(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\ProjectHasPerson", "project_id", "id");
    }
}
```

Модель ProjectHasPerson

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProjectHasPerson extends Model
{
    protected $table = "project_has_people";
    //

    public function person(){
        return $this->hasOne("App\NaturalPerson", "id", "person_id");
    }
}
```

Persons оставил как есть

В контроллере передаю модель

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ProjectHasPerson;
use App\Projects;
use App\NaturalPerson;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        /*$persons = NaturalPerson::all();
        $projectHas = ProjectHasPerson::all();*/
        $projects = Projects::all();
        return view("projects.index")->with("projects", $projects);
    }
}
```

Промежуточную таблицу я получаю через $project->has, а вот $project->has->person уже нет. Натолкните на путь истинный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для `Person`

```
public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
    }
```

для `Project`

```
public function persons()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person');
        }
```

и теперь через `$project->persons`(коллекция) будет работать, и измените название модели(уберите букву s в конце), Здесь можно подробно прочитать об этом https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships#mm

Comment: Спасибо! А каким образом подбираются ключи? Не лучше ли их указывать явно? Какой смысл убирать s(стиль или функция)?

Comment: Как определяется промежуточная таблица без явного указания?

Comment: прочтите документацию, которую я указал в ответе, там все очень подробно описанно